# Unable to build Windows CE Cab Project since Windows 10 1809

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, cabwiz

After upgrading to Windows 10 1809, I'm unable to build a Cab Project in Visual Studio 2008 Pro.  The application we're packaging into a CAB file is for Windows CE 6.0, hence the ancient version of Visual Studio.

I can see in the output window that the following command is run:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\smartdevices\sdk\sdktools\cabwiz.exe" "C:\VB2008PRO\Stock System v4.0.6764.19135\CABProject\Release\CABProject.inf" /dest "C:\VB2008PRO\Stock System v4.0.6764.19135\CABProject\Release\" /err CabWiz.log
```

If I run this myself, I see the exit code was 1, so something went wrong.

The output I see in the CabWiz.log file is:

```
Warning: Section [RegKeys] has no data
Warning: Section [DefaultInstall] key "AddReg" - there are no section entries to process
Error: CAB file "C:\VB2008PRO\Stock System v4.0.6764.19135\CABProject\Release\CABProject.CAB" could not be created
```

So I can see that the CABProject.CAB file cannot be created, but what's the reason??  I tried disabling anti-virus temporarily, but that wasn't the reason.

I can't be the only one to have tried this in Windows 1809... has anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Seemingly, to build CAB projects in Windows, you need to have 8.3 file name creation enabled and ensure that your files have 8.3 file names after you re-enable it.

1. Check if 8.3 file names are enabled on the volume where your project is located, using [fsutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/ff621566(v=ws.11)).

   C:\Users\matty>fsutil 8dot3name query c:
   The volume state is: 0 (8dot3 name creation is enabled).
   The registry state is: 0 (Enable 8dot3 name creation on all volumes).

   **Based on the above settings, 8dot3 name creation is enabled on c:**
2. If 8dot3 name creation is disabled, enable it in the registry or via the command line:

   fsutil 8dot3name set C: 1

This operation takes effect immediately (no reboot required).

4. Archive and delete the files and then extract them back to the same location.  This is the only reliable way I found of getting Windows to generate all the 8dot3 file names for all files in the project.
5. Build your CAB project!